# Select with union all statement throw exception : no such column : borrow

Tags: android, sqlite, join, android-sqlite, union

I have a table with money items stored in it, by date.
Some money items are typed as loan and others as borrow.

What I want to do, is put in a ListView 3 elements: the date, the sum of loan amount for this date, the sum of borrowed amount for this date.

Here is my code to fill my cursor:

```
Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT date_o, loan, borrow FROM " +
                        "(SELECT strftime('%m', date) as date_o, SUM(amount) as loan FROM " +
                        "(SELECT date, amount FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE date > date('now', '-6 months') AND TYPE = " + ActivityClass.DATABASE_LOAN_TYPE + " ORDER BY date DESC) " +
                        "GROUP BY strftime('%m', date) " +
                        "UNION ALL " +
                        "SELECT strftime('%m', date) as date_o, SUM(amount) as borrow FROM " +
                        "(SELECT date, amount FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE date > date('now', '-6 months') AND TYPE = " + ActivityClass.DATABASE_BORROW_TYPE + " ORDER BY date DESC) " +
                        "GROUP BY strftime('%m', date)) GROUP BY date_o", null);
```

And here is the code to fill my ListView:

```
List<List<Float>> amountByMonth = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Float> data = new ArrayList<>();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                data.add(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(0)));
                data.add(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(1)));
                data.add(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(2)));
                amountByMonth.add(data);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

So my function then returns a `List<List<Float>>`.

The issue I got is:

```
Couldn't read row 0, col 2 from CursorWindow
```

So my investigation shows that the `cursor.getString(2)` does not exist (throw exception), and I think that my query is badly constructed.

The table detail is the following:

```
private static final String TABLE_MONEY = "money",
            KEY_MONEY_ID = "id",
            KEY_MONEY_TITLE = "title",
            KEY_MONEY_AMOUNT = "amount",
            KEY_MONEY_DETAILS = "details",
            KEY_MONEY_DATE = "date",
            KEY_MONEY_TYPE_FK_ID = "type",
            KEY_MONEY_CONTACT_FK_ID = "contact",
            KEY_MONEY_REMINDER_FK_ID = "reminder";
```

If you need further details, do not hesitate to ask.

EDIT : I modified my query since I was testing in //.
the issue I got here is that the column borrow is not known.

Comment: Thanks Rotwang, but can't you just help me? I think maybe it's a JOIN I need, don't you think? Is there a way to help instead of feeling upset in your comments? Would really help me (and thanks for the minus 1).

Comment: Hi Rotwang, sry for my post, really thought you were upset. For your solution, it's working perfectly fine (clue : same number of columns and fake columns), my mistake : thinking loan and borrow would have auto completed themselves as 2nd and 3rd columns of my request.

Comment: It's OK. One suggestion: study the logic of the SQL statements you're going to use to avoid such errors in the future.

Comment: I converted my comments to an answer, so that you can accept it and remove your post from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you pretend to read **3** columns when selecting only **2**: `SELECT strftime('%m', date) as date_o, SUM(amount) as loan ...`

When you use the `UNION` clause, you must have the **same columns** in all your subqueries (`loan` and `borrow` aren't the same column).
You can use `0 AS borrow` and `0 AS loan` in your respective subqueries as fake column placeholders for the 3rd column.

I.e.:

```
Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT date_o, loan, borrow FROM " +
    "(SELECT strftime('%m', date) as date_o, SUM(amount) as loan, 0 AS borrow FROM " +
    "(SELECT date, amount FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE date > date('now', '-6 months') AND TYPE = " + ActivityClass.DATABASE_LOAN_TYPE + " ORDER BY date DESC) " +
    "GROUP BY strftime('%m', date) " +
    "UNION ALL " +
    "SELECT strftime('%m', date) as date_o, 0 AS loan, SUM(amount) as borrow FROM " +
    "(SELECT date, amount FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE date > date('now', '-6 months') AND TYPE = " + ActivityClass.DATABASE_BORROW_TYPE + " ORDER BY date DESC) " +
    "GROUP BY strftime('%m', date)) GROUP BY date_o", null);
```

Comment: Still smthg missing, this solve my error thrown, but it seems that the second Select erase the first loan data. I mean I hope to get for example cursor(0) with a date, cursor(1) with value1 and cursor(2) with value2. I currently get all the cursor(1) with 0. Still stuck sry.

Comment: The results displayed are incorrects. Maybe I should create another post. This one was dealing with the exception trhown and it's now resolved.

Comment: Quick tip: You can use SQLite Manager (a FireFox addon) to fast-check your SQL queries and commands on a copy of your database. I find it very useful.